# JSON_MERGE does not exist

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a problem with a stored procedure I want to write.
In this SP I have a JsonInput and I have a value from a table in my database.
I want to read the JsonInput and use the information to search for an value in my table. Then find the value and add it to my JsonOutput.

code looks like this:

```
declare @JsonInput nvarchar(MAX),
@JsonOutput nvarchar(MAX) 

set @JsonInput= N'{"Year":2022,"Surname":"Axel","Land":"Asia"}'

select @JsonInput

--define local variables
declare @name nvarchar(50), 
        @year int,
        @land nvarchar(50),
        @value nvarchar(50)
        

-- get json input data for dataset
set @name = JSON_VALUE(@JsonInput,'$.Surname')
set @year = JSON_VALUE(@JsonInput,'$.Year')
set @land = JSON_VALUE(@JsonInput,'$.Land')

--get  value
select @value = [Value] from  dbo.myTable  where ID='6' and [Year]=@year and Land=@land
select @value 

set @JsonOutput = (
select *
from dbo.myTable  where Surname=@name and [Year]=@year and Land=@land
for json auto)

Set @JsonOutput = JSON_MERGE(jsonColumn, '{"MyValue":"@value"}')
select @JsonOutput
```

Maybe you guys can help me to achieve my goal.
The result should look like this:

```
'{"Year":2022,"Surname":"Axel","Land":"Asia","MyValue":"3" }'
```

in The error messege is following text:
'JSON_MERGE' is not a recognized built-in function name.
but I dont know which other function I can use or to write it different
Thanks a lot

Comment: You've tagged both SQL Server and MySQL here; what are you *really* using? The above looks like T-SQL, and  SQL Server has no [`JSON_MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management studio 2018, sorry for confuson

Comment: @Natrium thanks for the Link. I have to check if one of the solutions is working for me

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application for SQL Server, @user19094279 , and there is no SSMS (or SQL Server) 2018.